# Invalid SQL statement when try to execute nested loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm working on a plsql script that assigns an indicator based on some qualifications. I've done this by trying to use 2 nested for loops. However when I try to execute I get the error "Invalid SQL statement" on line 2. I've looked through it over and over and can't find any issues. Any help is appreciated.

```
begin
for rec in (select prgm_id, (prgm_cntl_pct * cntl_count) as cntl from tmp_prgm_cntl) loop
  for rec2 in (select * from tmp_cust_pop tcp where tcp.prgm_id = rec.prgm_id and rownum <= rec.cntl order by tcp.rand_num) loop 
  insert into fact_cust_trgt_pop (fact_cust_trgt_pop_id, stg_prgm_cust_trgt_pop_id, cust_nbr, cust_id,
                              prgm_id, prgm_name, prgm_cntl_ind, cmpg_cntl_ind, cust_open_dt, cre_dt, updt_dt)
(select
  (select dmbs_random.value(1,200)from dual) as fact_cust_trgt_pop_id,
  rec2.stg_cust_trgt_pop_id,
  sctp.cust_nbr,
  sctp.cust_id,
  sctp.prgm_id,
  sctp.prgm_name,
  1 as prgm_cntl_ind,
  (select (dmbs_random.value(0,2)) case when <=1 then 'a' else 'b' as cmpg_cntl_ind end from dual) as cmpg_cntl_ind, 
  sctp.prgm_cust_open_dt,
  sctp.cre_dt,
  sctp.updt_dt
 from 
  stg_cust_trgt_pop sctp
  join sc45437.stg_cust_trgt_pop sctp
  on
  sctp.stg_cust_trgt_pop_id = tcp.stg_cust_trgt_pop_id); 
 end loop;
end loop;
end;
```

Comment: 1) "select
      (select dmbs_random.value(1,200)..."  - columns list is missed.
   
2) "if (select dmbs_random.value(0,2) from dual) <= 1 then ''a'' as cmpg_cntl_ind else ''b'' as cmpg_cntl_ind end if," - wrong statement,
IF can't be used in SQL, it's PL/SQL flow control. Use CASE instead.

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov I made those changes and still get the same error.

Comment: (select dmbs_random.value(1,200)from dual) as fact_cust_trgt_pop_id is the overkill. Also you have syntax error. Use simply "select dBms_random.value(1,200) as fact_cust_trgt_pop_id..."

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov the questions is updated with the code

Comment: You appear to be trying to use dynamic PL/SQL.  But the PL/SQL block you're constructing is incomplete (no `BEGIN` and `END`, for example).  More importantly, though, there appears to be no need to use dynamic PL/SQL in the first place.  Unless there is some tremendous advantage that isn't obvious from your simplified example, just use plain static PL/SQL.

Comment: execute immediate should use PL/SQL block form ('BEGIN...END;') and looks useless in your case.

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov If I take it out of the execute immediate statement I get an error that the for loop is an unknown command

Comment: case when (select dmbs_random.value(0,2) from dual) <=1 then ''a'' as cmpg_cntl_ind else ''b'' as cmpg_cntl_ind end - again code error. Please study the documentation for CASE statement - this saves your time: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Comment: When you get rid of execute immediate check carefuly you get rid of all unrequired quotations like ''a''

Comment: @DmitryNikiforov thanks for the help. I updated the code in the question. I now get an error about the 'from' on that case statement.

Comment: Use the following case statement: case when dmbs_random.value(0,2) <=1 then 'a' else 'b' end as cmpg_cntl_ind instead of (select (dmbs_random.value(0,2)) case when <=1 then 'a' else 'b' as cmpg_cntl_ind end from dual) as cmpg_cntl_ind